# What do square brackets in class names mean?

Tags: html

I saw [here](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) square brackets that are used in class names:

```
<input class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]]" name="firstname" type="text" />
```

What do these square brackets mean?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That is most likely used by some sort of validator or validation library. The class here means that validate this field denoted by `validate` keyword and then:

`required` it is required field
`custom` validation type; allow only letters
`length` should be between 0 to 100 chars

Well, this information is used by the jQuery validation library you posted the [link](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) to :)

Answer (score 145):

The square brackets are used as an attribute selector, to select all elements that have a certain attribute value. In other words, they detect attribute presence.

**Example 1:**

```
img[alt="picName"] {width:100px;}
```

would affect only

```
<img src="picName.png" alt="picName" />
```

in your code, and won't affect

```
<img src="picName.png" alt="picName2" />
```

**Example 2:**

The following affects all elements with title attribute specified:

```
[title] {border:1px dotted #333;}
```

**Example 3:**

This CSS

```
p[class~="fancy"]
```

will affect the following html

```
<p class="fancy">Hello</p>
<p class="very fancy">Hola</p>
<p class="fancy maybe">Aloha</p>
```

but won't affect this:

```
<p class="fancy-fancy">Privet</p>
```

**Example 4:**

```
[lang|="en"]
```

will affect elements with lang attribute, which is hyphen-separated list of words beginning with “en”, like

```
<div lang="en">Tere</div>
<div lang="en-gb">GutenTag</div>
```

**Examples 5, 6, 7:**(CSS3)

The following attribute selector affects link elements whose href attribute value starts with the string “http:”.

```
a[href^="http:"]
```

The following attribute selector affects image elements whose src attribute values ends with the string “.png”.

```
img[src$=".png"]
```

The following attribute selector affects any input element whose name attribute value contains the string “choice”.

```
input[name*="choice"]
```

Comment: While this information is correct, it is not the context the OP asked for... Both square bracket syntaxes have nothing in common which each other.

Comment: Perhaps the author was not aware of the scope of his/her question and this thorough answer cleared up confusion about the different uses of this square bracket syntax.

Comment: What is the difference between using `p[class~="fancy"]` and `p.fancy`?

Comment: @rybo111, none! but you can use img[alt~="fancy"].

Comment: Why won't `p[class~="fancy"]` match `<p class="fancy-fancy">Privet</p>`

Comment: @punstress because it matches only elements which have a class 'fancy'. If we are dealing with a class in the first place, we should just use p.fancy . With advanced selectors we can select elements with other attributes, such as name, alt, title, for ...

Comment: Ah, at the time I guess I was thinking it would match any class containing the letters 'fancy.' Ty.

Comment: Valuable information, but it doesn't answer the question that the OP asked, which wasn't about brackets in CSS selectors, but their usage in the value of the class attribute on HTML elements.

Comment: @paceaux, check a comment from 14.08.2010 :)

Comment: @JevgeniBogatyrjov — Which is also correct. This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Square brackets can go into the classnames in the HTML direct, which is what the OP was asking about. NOT square brackets in CSS. Example, <p class="[ some-class ]">.

Comment: This is a fun example of finding the information I needed, despite the question not being my situation. Googled "css square brackets meaning" to learn about attribute selectors.

Answer (score 31):

Apart from the use-case / example given by the OP for brackets in class names, there is also another use case which Harry Roberts proposed (and later stopped proposing) in his blog a while back: [grouping related classes in your markup](http://csswizardry.com/2014/05/grouping-related-classes-in-your-markup/) where the square brackets could be used to group

> two or more related class attributes to make them easier to notice
>   when scanning an HTML file
>
> ...
>
> and that looks something like this:

```
<div class="[ foo  foo--bar ]  baz">
```

where:

> - There must be more than one ‘set’ of classes.
> - One ‘set’ must contain    more than one class.

He also noted that adding the brackets is completely valid according to the html5 spec

> There are no […] restrictions on the tokens authors can use in the
>   class attribute…

**Just to reiterate:**

The brackets in the class attributes - while being valid CSS class names are *not actually meant to be used in the CSS*<sup>1</sup> - but rather to help readability in the HTML.

---

Notes:

<sup>1</sup>
[Although technically, they can be used when escaped](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/BzjjvV),

```css
.\[ {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="[">Hi there</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Nothing. Brackets are a legal character for class names with no special meaning whatsoever.

Comment: But they do have meaning in css files, so best not to use class names like this for styling. This stuff should probably go in a custom validation attribute.

Answer (score 6):

In standard HTML, they have no particular meaning.  It's just more text.

To the jQuery Validation plugin, they do.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```css
[what-ever] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<p what-ever>Hello</p>
```

---

This will color Hello red. You can use square-bracket as class names

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular rule within a class name. In your example they are almost certainly being used by a JavaScript validation framework. This is because in HTML you can't simply add your own attributes to tags, therefore the validation framework is exploiting the fact that CSS class names can contain such characters in order to 'store' the validation rules within the class name. There won't actually be any corresponding class in the style-sheet - this is just a trick to work around the limitations of HTML.

Comment: Actually, in HTML5 you *can* add your own attributes, as long as they begin with the string `data-`. They were added specifically to make such abuses of classes unnecessary.