# CSS attribute selectors

Tags: css, attributes, css-selectors

I study about css in [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) . The css selectors table has rows :

> [attribute|=value]

- [lang|=en] Selects all elements with a lang attribute value starting with "en"

> [attribute^=value]

- a[src^="https"] Selects every  element whose src attribute value begins with "https"

What differences between [attr |= value] and [attr ^= value] except double quotes ?

Comment: See answers in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483391/what-does-square-brackets-in-css-class-names-means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[attr|=value]
Represents an element with an attribute name of attr whose value is a hyphen-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "value". It can be used for language subcode matches.

[attr^=value]
Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is the prefixed by "value".

Have a look at [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com)

I recommend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Attribute_selectors and the whole MDN

Comment: Almost :-) The question was about differences between `|=` and `^=` but the OP can now read it for themselves ;-) Interestingly even on the [W3's own page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) `^=` isn't mentioned. +1 for also mentioning **w3fools**

Comment: @Havelock: Because `^=` isn't in CSS2, it's in sel3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors

Comment: This has nothing to do with double quotes by the way. It's just W3Schools being lazy and inconsistent.

Comment: Hmm, MDN says "one of which is exactly" but W3 says "beginning (from the left) with". Which one is correct?

Comment: @pimvdb: The W3C spec is correct. MDN is also inaccurate here, but thankfully Firefox implements it correctly anyway.