# How to manage two different font files when language changes

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

I have a vue application that is multi-language (which for that I used i18n) and I need to handle the font-family for each language in different css file.

I had an idea that I can import css files conditionally but I don't know how.

Does anybody else have any idea or solution for my problem?

There are two different css file like this and each render different font from other:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Questrial";
  src: url("../../fonts/Questrial-Regular.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Galano_Grotesque_extra_Bold";
  src: url("../../fonts/Galano_Grotesque_Bold.otf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Galano_Grotesque_Bold";
  src: url("../../fonts/Galano_Grotesque_DEMO_Bold.otf");
}
```

If I want to say that in other word, my application has "English" and "Persian" language.
When app locale is English I need to render en-css.css file and when the locale is Persian I need to render fa-css.css file.

I would be glad to hear about your ideas :)

Comment: Is your application setting the `lang` attribute of your `html`-tag correctly according to your delivered language? If yes, you could use a [attribute selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172943/css-attribute-selectors) to change the font according to the value.

Comment: @FabianS. yes it does. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could use your `html`-tags `lang` attribute to overwrite the used font-family on your html tag according to your applications language.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Questrial";
  src: url("../../fonts/Questrial-Regular.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Galano_Grotesque_extra_Bold";
  src: url("../../fonts/Galano_Grotesque_Bold.otf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Galano_Grotesque_Bold";
  src: url("../../fonts/Galano_Grotesque_DEMO_Bold.otf");
}


/* english font default */

html {
  font-family: "Questrial";
}


/* other font for persian */

html[lang="fa"] {
  font-family: "Galano_Grotesque_Bold";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your idea. But when I change language the lang attribute in the html element do not update and remains same.

Comment: @NiazEstefaie you mean the language of your application changes but the `lang` attribute doesnt? So your page shows persian content but the `lang` attribute is still `en`? That should not be the case, the `lang` attribute always should represent the contents language.

Comment: Yes the lang attribute does not update when the language changes.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can't change the `lang` attribute, you can use unicode-range in font definitions. For Languages using the basic Latin alphabet:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Questrial";
  src: url("../../fonts/Questrial-Regular.ttf");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

And for Persian (using Vazir as a sample Persian font),

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Vazir";
  src: url("../../fonts/vazir.ttf");
  unicode-range: U+0660-0669, U+06F0-06F9;
}
```

The above Unicode ranges might need adjustments depending on your application requirements.